# Securing our roof against possums

Tags: roof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Animal in the attic (possibly a raccoon)](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4263/animal-in-the-attic-possibly-a-raccoon)

We have just finished a major renovation of our house. Since complete, a possum has taken up residence in our roof. Unfortunately, it is living in the floor space between the ground and first floors and we have little or no access to this area. We have sprayed "Poss-off" in as many places as possible and cut all trees next to our house to reduce access but every night he comes back. I suspect that he is either walking along the power line (although it has a possum guard, I found possum scat under it) or climbing up the pipes to our pool's solar water system (50mm).

So the questions are:

1. what more can I do to discourage him
2. if we have it professionally removed (they are a protected species), will another one just take over.

Comment: @allindal  - Thanks, I'll have a squiz. I searched on possum, should have checked for generic animals.

Comment: Solution: we tried various things to get rid of our possum, even trapping and dumping a decent distance away. It came back. Eventually, we just contacted a professional possum removalist and it was dealt within in a hour. He found the hole, blocked it and put a one-way door for the animals (yep, plural) to get out. Cost $400 but at least it is now dealt with.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem in my house in Georgia with a number of animals, to solve I put my cat in the attic for a few hours a day for a week or so (usually when I was up there anyway). The cat never killed anything, (to my knowledge) but the scent of the cat drove the animals out for good. I have found this solution to be simple, cheap, and effective. It also works with dogs.

Comment: Good idea. We have a useless cat (lets pigeons share his food while he eats), but perhaps we can spread some cat hair around or put one of his old blankets up there.

Comment: Followup: tried putting the cat in the roof - no difference. Useless cat. The next thing I'll try is putting some cat scat on the roof near the power line where the possum is coming across.